# elasticsearch:how to define index exactly with analyzer,tokenizer and filter

Tags: elasticsearch

//this is not working and showing error while creating index...
//unexcepted character c and it come according to custome field

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/sports0/' -d" 
  "settings":{
    "analysis":{
      "analyzer":{
        "autocomplete":{
          "type":"custom",
          "tokenizer":"standard",
          "filter":[ "standard", "lowercase", "stop", "kstem", "ngram" ] 
        `enter code here`}
      },
           filter:{  
              type:"stop" ,stopwords:"stopwords.txt"
}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You forgot the first `{`.
- Some string aren't wrapped in double quotes.

And please do a better formatting of the json.